# How to properly process the received JSON and output information from it?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

tell me how to process this JSON file. I need to display the Group array to the screen as a list. I just recently started to understand SWIFT, so I would be glad to receive any help.

I've tried writing code like this to parse JSON:

```
struct Post: Decodable{
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var img: String?
    
    var idproduct: Int?
    var nameproduct: String?
    var textproduct: String?
    var priceproduct: Int?
    var unitproduct: String?
    var indexproduct: String?
    var imgproduct: String?
    
    var groupsproduct: [String] = []
    enum group: String, CodingKey {
            case id
            case name
            case img
    }
    enum Product: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case price
        case unit
        case index
        case img
        case group
        case text
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: group.self)

             self.id = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
             self.name = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
             self.img = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .img)
        
                let container2 = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Product.self)

        self.idproduct = try? container2.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.nameproduct = try? container2.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.textproduct = try? container2.decode(String.self, forKey: .text)
        self.priceproduct = try? container2.decode(Int.self, forKey: .price)
        self.unitproduct = try? container2.decode(String.self, forKey: .unit)
        self.indexproduct = try? container2.decode(String.self, forKey: .index)
        self.imgproduct = try? container2.decode(String.self, forKey: .img)
        self.groupsproduct = try! container2.decode([String].self, forKey: .group)

        }
}
```

Here is the JSON I need to parse:

> ```
> {
> "id": "abs",
> "name": "Testname",
> "img": ""
> }
> ],
> "goods": [
> {
> "id": 1000,
> "name": "test",
> "text": "",
> "price": 75,
> "unit": "",
> "index": "",
> "img": "",
> "groups": [
> ""
> ]
> }
> }
> ```

P.S. I am using SwiftUI 2

Comment: That's not valid json. Once you have sorted out what your json actually is then I would suggest using https://quicktype.io to get a structure for decoding your json

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, thank for help) Its work for me)